" RUN TIME ERROR: Compilation error on line 12. Dimension mismatch taking subset of lambda"
I'm writing a model to use with JAGS but the return is :
" RUN TIME ERROR: Compilation error on line 12.   Dimension mismatch taking subset of lambda"
But I dont know what to do more (I checked the values of npixel, cell_area...)
the code is providning from this site :  https://masonfidino.com/bayesian_integrated_model/
thank you so much for you help from a MasterStudent
here, the model :
model {
  # The latent-state model
  for(pixel in 1:npixel){
    log(**lambda**[pixel]) <-inprod(x_s[pixel,], beta[pixel]) + cell_area[pixel]
    z[pixel] ~ dbern(1 - exp(-lambda[pixel]))
    logit(b[pixel]) <-  inprod(h_s[pixel,] , cc[pixel])}
  
  #psi[pixel] <- 1 - exp(-lambda[pixel])
  #z[pixel] ~ dbern(psi[pixel])
  
  # The presence_only data model
  for(t in 1:1){
  for(po in 1:npo){
    po_denominator[po] <- inprod(lambda[1:npixel,t], b[1:npixel,t])/npo[po]
    ones[po] ~ dbern(
      exp(
        log(lambda[po_pixel[po]]*b[po_pixel[po]]) -
          log(po_denominator[po])) / cste)} }
  
  # Detection / non-detection data model
  for(site in 1:nsite){
    logit(rho[site]) <- inprod(v[pa_pixel[site], ],a)
    y[site] ~ dbin( 
      z[pa_pixel[site]] * rho[site],K[site]
    )
    } 
  
  # Priors for latent state model
  for(latent in 1:**nlatent**){  #here, nlatent = 1 
    **beta**[latent] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)} 
  # Priors for presence-only data model
  for(po in 1:npar_po){
    cc[po] ~ dlogis(0, 1)}
  # Priors for det/non-det data model
  for(pa in 1:npar_pa){
    a[pa] ~ dlogis(0, 1)}
  
  zsum <- sum(z)
}

I tried to check if the rest of the code is valid and to run JAGS but with no success ...

It seems like you've modified my code a bit. One thing to know is that JAGS skips empty lines, so line 12 is:
po_denominator[po] <- inprod(lambda[1:npixel,t], b[1:npixel,t])/npo[po]

So, given the error, I would check the dimensions you input to lambda, b, and npo. Of those, you index b as a vector earlier in the code but then index as a matrix on this line (b[pixel] vs b[1:npixel,t]). This is a dimension mismatch. So, if that is the only issue, then you could modify that line to:
po_denominator[po] <- inprod(lambda[1:npixel,t], b[1:npixel])/npo[po]

But, in general, it seems like you don't have data across multiple primary sampling periods. As such, you can just drop the temporal for loop. Something like this may work (you did not supply data so it's not like I can test it):
model {
  # The latent-state model
  for(pixel in 1:npixel){
    log(lambda[pixel]) <-inprod(x_s[pixel,], beta[pixel]) + cell_area[pixel]
    z[pixel] ~ dbern(1 - exp(-lambda[pixel]))
    logit(b[pixel]) <-  inprod(h_s[pixel,] , cc[pixel])}
  
  # The presence_only data model
  for(po in 1:npo){
    po_denominator[po] <- inprod(lambda[1:npixel], b[1:npixel])/npo[po]
    ones[po] ~ dbern(
      exp(
        log(lambda[po_pixel[po]]*b[po_pixel[po]]) -
          log(po_denominator[po])) / cste)
  }
  
  # Detection / non-detection data model
  for(site in 1:nsite){
    logit(rho[site]) <- inprod(v[pa_pixel[site], ],a)
    y[site] ~ dbin( 
      z[pa_pixel[site]] * rho[site],K[site]
    )
    } 
  
  # Priors for latent state model
  for(latent in 1:nlatent){  #here, nlatent = 1 
    beta[latent] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)} 
  # Priors for presence-only data model
  for(po in 1:npar_po){
    cc[po] ~ dlogis(0, 1)}
  # Priors for det/non-det data model
  for(pa in 1:npar_pa){
    a[pa] ~ dlogis(0, 1)}
  
  zsum <- sum(z)
}


